# SQL - Space/blank character code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to include a space/blank character in a query. I'm using a CASE condition which classify values write like : 'Syrah N', 'Chardonnay B', ... There is a space between my value and a capital letter. When the value started with the looked letter, query is useless (ex : 'Barbaroux RS' is classified B, but it must be RS).

Actual query

```
SELECT name
CASE 
   WHEN name LIKE '%N%' THEN 'Red'
   WHEN name LIKE '%B%' THEN 'White'
   WHEN name LIKE '%RS%' THEN 'Green'
   ELSE 'Other'
END 
FROM mytable
```

Wanted query

```
SELECT name
CASE 
   WHEN name LIKE '% N %' THEN 'Red'
   WHEN name LIKE '% B %' THEN 'White'
   WHEN name LIKE '% RS %' THEN 'Green'
   ELSE 'Other'
END 
FROM mytable
```

How can i write '%*space*B*space*%' ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's PostgreSQL 9.1.18

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space character before and one after name, then do your `LIKE`:

```
SELECT name
CASE 
   WHEN ' ' || name || ' ' LIKE '% N %' THEN 'Red'
   WHEN ' ' || name || ' ' LIKE '% B %' THEN 'White'
   WHEN ' ' || name || ' ' LIKE '% RS %' THEN 'Green'
   ELSE 'Other'
END 
FROM mytable
```

`||` is ANSI SQL concatenation. Some dbms products have other constructions...

Comment: It's ok for me (PostgreSQL 9.1.18). How can i precise multiple values per case ? `('%N%','%Noir%','%NOIR%','%noir%') `

Comment: Do `OR` between the `LIKE`s. Perhaps you should consider adding an extra column to you table?

Comment: It's ok. Example `when ' ' || name || ' ' like '%RS%' or ' ' || name || ' ' like '%Rs%' then 'Green'`  Thanks